# Difference between RWND and RWIN?

Tags: tcp, terminology

I stumble upon both abbreviations in the same context and it seems they are used interchangeably. But I'd like clarification if this is actually the case or if there are differences between the two.

The answer may be as simple as *“the two are the same”* but it would be very nice to see some proof. I failed to find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [diffs of draft-ietf-ippm-tcp-throughput-tm](http://tools.ietf.org/wg/ippm/draft-ietf-ippm-tcp-throughput-tm/draft-ietf-ippm-tcp-throughput-tm-11-from-10.diff.txt):

This diff seems to show all the RWIN abberviations being replaced with RWND, below is an example.

```
    It is important to clarify the interaction between the sender's Send
-   Socket Buffer and the receiver's advertised TCP RWIN Size.  TCP test
-   programs such as iperf, ttcp, etc. allow the sender to control the
+   Socket Buffer and the receiver's advertised TCP RWND Size.  TCP test
+   programs such as iperf, ttcp, etc. allows the sender to control the
```

The latest version of this document, [RFC 6349](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6349), doesn't have RWIN anywhere in it.  Looks like they mean the same thing to me.

Comment: I'll give others the chance to come up with an even better answer, but yours is already top notch and I'll accept it if nobody else has a better one. I mean, if they are able to simply search & replace it, then it must be the same (as I thought as well). Many thanks!